# Sql delete multiple rows with multiple identifier

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm trying to delete multiple row by two identifier:

```
DELETE FROM [Customers] 
WHERE (City,Country) IN (('Buenos Aires', 'Argentina'), ('Graz', 'Austria'))
```

And i'm getting this error:

```
Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 row value misused)
```

It's not possible to delete multiple rows with multiple identifiers?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you database doesn't support tuples, just use explicit `AND`/`OR` logic:

```
DELETE FROM [Customers] 
WHERE (City = 'Buenos Aires' AND Country = 'Argentina') OR
      (City = 'Graz' AND Country = 'Austria');
```

Comment: Thank! It's possible to remove with OR more than 100 rows in one statement?

Comment: That depends on the database, which is not tagged.